# Failed to load template magento

Tags: magento-1.7, template

On home page cms, I have added block as below :

```
{{block type='page/html' as='homepagecategories' template='page/html/homepagecategories.phtml'}}
```

And I am trying to load few of the categories as below

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(); 
$homeCategoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->setStoreId($store)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('display_on_home_page',1)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('url_path')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('display_on_home_page'); 
foreach($homeCategoryCollection as $cat) {
 //category display output
}
```

when I comment foreach block, I am able to see my homepage but if I remove that comment, It gives me following log in system.

```
2014-03-10T15:07:42+00:00 DEBUG (7): Failed to load template:/mystorepath/default/template/page/html/homepagecategories.phtml
```

I have created "display_on_home_page" category attribute(dropdown) using extension and I am able to see dropdown in the backend. Any suggestion to move further?

Answer (score 2):

I think the error can't be better:

> **Failed to load template:** /mystorepath/default/template/page/html/homepagecategories.phtml

So either the template doesn't exist or you have a spelling error, maybe uppercase/lowercase problem? Or there is a symlink to the template and you don't allow using symlinks in the backend:

```
System > Configuration > Developer > Template Settings > Allow Symlinks
```

Comment: There won't be any chance of uppercase/lowercase problem, cause template is currently working. I have added above line of codes in it.

Comment: I actually want to know when can this be possible.

Comment: If you comment the foreach block everything is fine? And if you have the foreach block, then you get this error!? Ok, I have NO clue. This doesn't make sense :-/

Comment: :) $homeCategoryCollection is the main issue over here...